# Как сохранить созданное PHP изображение?

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.

Есть страница image.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <body>
  <a href="image.php">сформировать фото</a>
 </body>
```

На image.php при помощи PHP  создаётся картинка, вот код:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$img = LoadJpeg(dirname(__FILE__).'/img/pic.jpg');
$font =dirname(__FILE__).'/font/pt_sans.ttf';
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
imagettftext ($img, 14, 0, 220, 100, $textcolor, $font, "1");
imagettftext ($img, 14, 0, 150, 150, $textcolor, $font, "2");
imagettftext ($img, 14, 0, 400, 550, $textcolor, $font, "3");
imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img); ?>
```

Мне надо, чтобы после формирования картинки она автоматически загрузилась на компьютер пользователя, и он прешел на страницу form.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте заголовок

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="imgName.jpg"');
```